# Why thumbnails don't load image Bootsrap

Tags: reactjs, grid, thumbnails

I´m working in a web page using react Js, because the full project is using this. I'm so new in react

I need to put four images links in a grid, but I cant do it working fine.
This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Col, Row, Thumbnail } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { firebaseConnect, pathToJS, dataToJS } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { refreshTableauTicket } from '../actions/TableauActions';
import {Grid, Container} from 'react-bootstrap';


const ProjectThumbnail = (props) => {
  let size ={
    width: 200,
    height: 240,
  };
  return(
    <Grid >
      <Row className="show-grid">
        <Col xs={12} md={8}>
          <Link to={props.url}>
          <Thumbnail src="/assets/5.jpg" style={size} alt='thumbnail'/>
          <h3>{props.nombreProyecto}</h3>
          </Link>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} md={8}>
          <Link to={props.url}>
          <Thumbnail src="/assets/5.jpg" style={size} alt='thumbnail'/>
          <h3>{props.nombreProyecto}</h3>
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row className="show-grid">
        <Col xs={12} md={8}>
          <Link to={props.url}>
          <Thumbnail src="/assets/5.jpg" style={size} alt='thumbnail'/>
          <h3>{props.nombreProyecto}</h3>
          </Link>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} md={8}>
          <Link to={props.url}>
          <Thumbnail src="/assets/5.jpg" style={size} alt='thumbnail'/>
          <h3>{props.nombreProyecto}</h3>
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  );
}

const ProjectSelect = (props) => {
  let userId = props.firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  let style = {'maxWidth':'80%'};
  return(
    <div style={style}>
      <Row onClick={props.refreshTableauTicket}>
        <ProjectThumbnail nombreProyecto='transmilenio carrera septima' url='/proyecto'/>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

//const wrappedSelection = firebaseConnect()(ProjectSelect)
const FirebaseConnected = firebaseConnect()(ProjectSelect)

const ProjectSelection = connect(
  ({firebase}) => ({
    auth: pathToJS(firebase, 'auth'),
  }),{refreshTableauTicket}
)(FirebaseConnected)

export default withRouter(ProjectSelection);
```

But with this code, the image dont load and the grid dont works fine, because the elements dont align each other

If you can explain why this doesnt works, I'll be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the thumbnail src within `{}`

```
const ProjectThumbnail = (props) => {
  let size ={
    width: 200,
    height: 240,
  };
  return(
    <Grid >
      <Row className="show-grid">
        <Col xs={12} md={8}>
          <Link to={props.url}>
          <Thumbnail src={"/assets/5.jpg"} style={size} alt='thumbnail'/>
          <h3>{props.nombreProyecto}</h3>
          </Link>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} md={8}>
          <Link to={props.url}>
          <Thumbnail src={"/assets/5.jpg"} style={size} alt='thumbnail'/>
          <h3>{props.nombreProyecto}</h3>
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row className="show-grid">
        <Col xs={12} md={8}>
          <Link to={props.url}>
          <Thumbnail src={"/assets/5.jpg"} style={size} alt='thumbnail'/>
          <h3>{props.nombreProyecto}</h3>
          </Link>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} md={8}>
          <Link to={props.url}>
          <Thumbnail src={"/assets/5.jpg"} style={size} alt='thumbnail'/>
          <h3>{props.nombreProyecto}</h3>
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```